Odd coloring of numbers in indented blocks
This answer includes a list of numbers in an indented block. See below screenshot:

Why do the numbers have odd coloring?

Eh...I mean ultimately Garbage In Garbage Out. It's applying Python syntax highlighting to just random numbers.

If the colouring of a list of arbitrary values inside a code block/fence that uses a language's highlight rules bothers you, then you could change the block/fence to not use a language's highlighting rules (none or lang-none).

@ThomA How does one do that with an indented block?

See What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?. (Of course, changing from a block to a fence is also an option.)

You unindent and add code fences. Maybe the <!-- language: lang-none --> hint would work but I'm pretty sure it's deprecated.

@ThomA I still don't understand why syntax highlighting would cause the first number to be displayed in orange, the second number to be displayed in white, and the third number to be displayed partially in orange and partially in white.

It appears that the syntax highlighter does not always recognise leading zeroes as part of a literal integer value in the Python language, @JohnGordon . If you feel it's a bug, then  [so] is the wrong place to raise it.

@ThomA Current Python doesn't allow leading zeroes in int literals (except to represent the number 0). Not that the syntax highlighting makes sense even then, but 0001 isn't a valid Python expression.

@khelwood if it's valid syntax for Python or not for a list of arbitrary values is irrelevant in my opinion. If we're going by that logic, the entire "Python" code block isn't valid syntax, so the highlighting is "doing its best".

While the question is a duplicate because it's about the filtering, I'm a little disappointed that nobody found the elegant recursive approach to direct generation. (Hint; if you're in the middle of generating a long valid output, you can append either 1 or 01. Do you see why?) (Note: the structure of the recursion gives a hint as to how much output to expect.)

@KarlKnechtel No, I don't see why.  How would that ever produce 1010?

You emit 1, then 01, then you aren't "in the middle" any more because you're only allowed to emit one more digit, so you have free choice of 0 and 1. (You know, a base case... for recursion...)

@KarlKnechtel Oh, I didn't recognize the significance of "in the middle".  Gotcha.
